# Cut polyline in QGIS 2.4

Tags: line, qgis-2

I want to shorten a feature (a polyline representing a road) in QGIS 2.4

In QGIS 2.0 there was "Split Features" tool in the "Advanced Digitizing" toolbar.

Here the icon:

[image]

I'm not able to do this again.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the feature selected that you want to split

From the Advanced Digitizing toolbar, select Split Features

Draw a line across the feature you want split

Right-click to finish the sketch

Your feature is not split at the intersection of the sketch and the original line.

EDIT: In QGIS v2.4+ it seems the "Split Features" function is found under the Edit menu if you have not enabled it in the toolbar (in the toolbar as "Advanced Digitizing").

[image]

Comment: This is what I was used to do with Qgis 2.0; Now with Qgis 2.4 I can't find the same plugin. If I try to install "DIGITIZING TOOLS" appear the message "the plugin is broken".

Comment: It's not a plugin, its a core toolbar / function... that screenshot is from QGIS 2.4. Can you find the toolbar? Right-click on the grey area near the existing toolbars and you'll see a list...choose 'advanced digitizing'

Comment: @Marchetto great! Don't forget to mark this as an answer if it works out! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Marchetto be sure to mark the answer that worked for you... thanks!